# Can't access nginx server from outside

Tags: nginx, centos, data-science-studio

I recently had to set up a nginx server on a centOS 7 server.
In order to run the dataiku software.

Every thing seems to run fine but once i try to access the pages i get absolutely nothing.

With elinks in local i manage to get the nginx default web page but not from my browser so i think it comes frommy nginx configuration.

here is my nginx.conf :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}



 http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And here is the default.conf included file :

```
server {
    listen       80 default;
    server_name _;
    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}
```

I really need this server running properly and being accessible do you have any idea ?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 19):

you should add a new rule on public zone, because CentOS 7 has a firewalld.
Try:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http
```

and go head!

Comment: this worked for. added https as well.

Comment: This was awesome. See below answer if you want this to persist after a reboot.

Answer (score 4):

Add the rule to the permanent set and reload FirewallD:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

That should work!

Comment: Thank you so much,

Answer (score 2):

You missed proxy_pass configuration which is actually translate all requests from backend to the outside via HTTP port 80 in your case:

```
server {
    # Host/port on which to expose Data Science Studio to users
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # Base url of the Data Science Studio installation
        proxy_pass http://DSS_HOST:DSS_PORT/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # Allow long queries
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        # Allow large uploads
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # Allow protocol upgrade to websocket
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Official documentation is pretty clear on that: http://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/installation/reverse_proxies.html

Make sure you have uptodated Nginx to be able to serve WebSocket requests.